# How to make a property optional but still use a regex?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Currently the validation is required for an email, how can I make this optional and still use the regex if the user enters an email?

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Errors), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Email_Val")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\w+([-+.]*[\w -]+)*@(\w+([-.]?\w+)){1,}\.\w{2,4}", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Errors), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RegExp_Val")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: All you need to do is remove the `RequiredAttribute`. A `RegularExpressionAttribute` is not evaluated if the value of the property is `null` (or empty string) either on the client or server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a non-capture group and use `?` like this:`^(?:\w+([-+.]*[\w -]+)*@(\w+([-.]?\w+)){1,}\.\w{2,4})?$`

It matches a blank field or an email that matches the regex.

Comment: looks like you can remove the ?: and it works still?

Comment: @coolbreeze yes, as long as you don't need the value of `$1`, which would refer to different groups without `?:`.

Comment: I'm not using any values, just looking for true or false.